# Infinite Textview with autoscrolling in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

Autoscroll in textview is implemented. But I am not able to implement the infinite textview.
I want to append the same text to the textview and infinitely scroll.....

The code for infinite scroll.......

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (scrollingTimer == nil) {
        scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.06)
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
    }
    self.textView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, -(self.textView.frame.size.height));
}

- (void) autoscrollTimerFired{
    CGPoint scrollPoint = self.textView.contentOffset;
    scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1);
    [self.textView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this by scrolling back to the beginning of the `UITextView` after your initial body text height has been reached.

Here is a sample that "infinitely" scrolls a random Lorem paragraph.

It duplicates the paragraph three times to ensure that it looks like it's scrolling forever.

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    UITextView *infiniteTextView;
    NSTimer *scrollTimer;

    CGFloat textHeight;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    // Create a text view
    infiniteTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];

    NSString *lorem = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n";

    infiniteTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    CGRect textBounds = [lorem boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(infiniteTextView.bounds.size.width - 16.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : infiniteTextView.font } context:nil];

    textHeight = textBounds.size.height;

    //Duplicate the paragraph 3 times
    infiniteTextView.text = [lorem stringByAppendingString:[lorem stringByAppendingString:lorem]];

    [self.view addSubview:infiniteTextView];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (scrollTimer == nil)
    {
        scrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.06)
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void) autoscrollTimerFired:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint scrollPoint = infiniteTextView.contentOffset;

    //Reset the scroll position if we exceed
    // the body paragraph height
    if( scrollPoint.y > textHeight )
    {
        scrollPoint.y = 0;
    }

    scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1);
    [infiniteTextView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
}

@end
```

(Try this on an iPhone Retina 4 inch target, it may need some adjusting for iPad.)